# Why doesn't my switch statement work?

Tags: javascript

Somehow I figure the "this" keyword isn't paying reference to the value.  However as you know I could use continual if/else if statements and it will work just fine.  For example I could write the code this way.

```
if(painStatus == 1) {
    msg.innerHTML = "pain message 1";
}
else if(painStatus == 2) {
    msg.innerHTML = "pain message 2";
}
```

so on and so forth, but using a switch statement it fails on me.  I'm sure it is something simple I am not doing right.  Sorry for being a noob.

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function painLevel(val) {
            var painStatus = document.getElementById("pain_status").innerHTML = val;
            var msg = document.getElementById("painMsg");

            switch (painStatus) {
                case 1:
                    msg.innerHTML = "Pain message 1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    msg.innerHTML = "Pain message 2";
                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                default:
                    msg.innerHTML = "";

            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Please use the bar to select pain level</p>
<p>My Pain Level</p>

    <input type = "range" min="0" max="10" value="1" onchange="painLevel(this.value)" />

        Pain Level = <span id="pain_status">1</span>
        <br /><br />

        <div id="painMsg"> rePain message 1</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `"1" !== 1`. `switch`/`case` statements use [strict comparison (`===`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and the `.value` of an `<input>` will always be a `String`.

Comment: I'm afraid to know what you're programming man...

Comment: ha thats funny, no its just using the pain scale that you see at doctors offices.  your comment made me chuckle though lol.

Comment: @dragonore lol, good :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just need to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) like this

```
switch (parseInt(painStatus)) {
// As before....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I knew it was something simple.  I suppose that makes sense since its treating the value as a string instead of number.